# How to make gvimdiff works under MobaXterm or cygwin?

Tags: vimdiff

I am using Mobaxterm which has cygwin tools.

vim/gvim are working fine. I am using same vimrc file for both (with -u option). Note that I have same issue without any vimrc file.

To make vimdiff works, I had to define diffexpr this way:

```
function MyDiffWin()
  let opt = ""
  if &diffopt =~ "icase"
    let opt = opt . "-i "
  endif
  if &diffopt =~ "iwhite"
    let opt = opt . "-b "
  endif
  execute '! ls '. v:fname_in
  silent execute "!/bin/diff.exe -a --binary " . opt . v:fname_in . " " . v:fname_new . " > " . v:fname_out
endfunction
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
```

But when I try to use gvimdiff, with same vimrc, I have the same issue I had with vimdiff without diffexpr :

```
E810: Cannot read or write temp files 
E97: Cannot create diffs
```

I tried to display the files used by diff.exe with the command `execute '! ls '. v:fname_in`
But it does not display anything :

```
:! ls /home/mobaxterm/tmp/vD9PXDX/0

Command terminated
```

So not surprising he cannot diff files !
But I do not understand the problem.

vim and gvim are in version 8.0.494

TIA

JP

Comment: What about `gvim`? Do you have the Cygwin version and does it work (with same vimrc)?

Comment: I have not installed the cygwin version. However I installed the windows gvim version and diff is working great with same vimrc. The only problem is that I have not succedeed to launch it from mobaxterm. Probably due to the fact that it can't find the windows diff.exe version plus other path issues.

Comment: In your code snippet, `diffexpr` is not set to the `MyDiffWin()` function defined above it.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem in MobaXTerm for a long time up to version 11.1. The reason (and solution) I finally found is twofold:

1. `E810` is about Vim being unable to write and read temporary files. If you run fugitive you get `E484` about the same.
2. `E97` is about wrong output of the `diff` executable called by Vim.

## Resolving `E810` and `E484`

In my case it was about wrong `set shellxquote=\"`, which I got during my searching for a solution. That setting is responsible for how Vim quotes filenames. Removing it, resulting in unsetting, resolved the error with writing and reading temporary files.

## Resolving `E97`

This is where the `diffexpr` comes to help. But it might not be sufficient itself. In my case I had to install `diffutils` package too as the `/bin/diff` was pointing to `busybox`, which supports *only* the unified diff format, while Vim requires ed-style (i.e. normal) diff format.

Now my diff executables are:

```bsh
lrwxrwxrwx     16 Jan 29 13:26 /bin/diff -> /bin/busybox.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 201.5K Dec  6  2016 /bin/diff.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x  56.0K Dec  6  2016 /bin/diff3.exe*
```

The difference in output is:

```bsh
$ /bin/diff one two
--- one
+++ two
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 no change
-file one
+file two
 no change

$ /bin/diff.exe one two
2c2
< file one
---
> file two
```

All that needs to be done is to point to the proper one in the `diffexpr` function:

```bsh
silent execute "!/bin/diff.exe  " . opt . v:fname_in . " " . v:fname_new . " > " . v:fname_out
```

Even the `-a --binary` options are not required.

Comment: On Win10 + Cygwin I have copied the `diff.exe` tool from the vim directory to the root directory and renamed it to `vimdiff.exe`. Changed `MyDiff()` accordingly to look for the file in `C:\ `. Yet, when gvim is started from the Cygwin command line, I get the `E97` error. Very frustrating.